# Is there a way to see your pokemons ivs in numbers?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Simply put, I want to breed for a 31/31 SpA/Spe IV Froakie, but I cannot tell if the IVs are 31 or not on Greninja because the IV judge doesn't say numbers. Is there a way to see numbers of IVs?

Answer (score 2):

Gen 6

Only give information on the best and worst stats and if any are the same value

Best stats ranges are:

IV range of 0-15: "It has rather decent stats, I'd say. That's how I judge it."

IV range of 16-25: "It's definitely got some good stats. That's how I judge it."

IV range 26-30: "This Pokémon has some fantastic stats. That's how I judge it."

IV of 31: "Stats like those... They simply can't be beat! That's how I judge it."

The closest you will get to an exact number is in Gen 7 and Gen 8 with the judging function.  It will get you a good read on if a pokemon has a perfect stat.

with the statement meaning:

IV of 0: "No Good"

IV range of 1-15: "Decent"

IV range of 16-25: "Pretty Good"

IV range 26-29: "Very Good"

IV of 30: "Fantastic"

IV of 31: "Best"

Information taken from: https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Stats_judge

Information for other pokemon games cam be found at the link

Comment: But Im playing X however and I took Greninja to the judge at he said the best is hp and all others are good too so it must be 6IV ja?

Comment: @ZaydenPlaysPokemon Just a heads up, it's highly recommended to add the tag of which game you are playing for more accurate answers. `pokemon-series` is pretty broad and the answer may vary based on the game

Comment: ok @wondercricket